# Battery Life of the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with andriod 4.4

Tags: battery-life, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Since the update on my Note 3, I have noticed a decrease in battery life. So my questions are, does the 17% increase in performance come in a decrease in battery life? Is it 4.4 using up more processing on my mobile CPU? What can I do to help with the battery life other than reverting back to 4.3?

Note: The Note 3 I posses is the T-Mobile version. Also I thank everybody in advance for the contribution of this post.

Comment: While waiting for a specific answer, you might wish to consult our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info), which gives some useful hints and first-aid.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same device, and I also had [battery-drain issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68865/what-is-trying-to-connect-to-the-network). The solution was to disable [Location Reporting](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3118687).

- Android Menu -> Location > Location Reporting.
- Turn them all off (one per account on the phone).

This **increased my battery life almost three-fold** and solved other issues that I was having with the device.